# In how many ways we can arrange $200$ people into two rooms, one with $150$ chairs and one with $100$ chairs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question has two parts, first is order doesn't matter. And second is when order matters. 
First part: I really have no idea, I tried lots of stuff but can't get how to deal with the 2 rooms and number of chairs in each room. 
 
For second part I thought that since the order matters, I can look at the $250$ chais as different chairs that I need to choose $200$ out of them to seat the people in, which is ($250$ choose $200$). But I still feel like I missed out on something since I didn't even look at the
 "$2$" rooms.
 
 Still new to combinatorics, I would really appreciate any help and explanation, and your ways of dealing with these questions.

Comment: If to approach the question without order first, I think we can visualize it like so: We take all 200 people in a row; then we just choose either 100, 101, 102, ... or 150 of them that go to the first room. The rest go to the second room. So I think the answer is
$$
\sum_{k=100}^{150} {200 \choose k} \approx 8.48 \times 10^{59}
$$
So this is assuming that everyone needs to have a seat ...

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks for the answer, I am not sure I understood you correctly. You're saying that the first room must have between 100 and 150 people, so we can either choose 100 from 200 or 101 from 200 .... until 150 from 200?, if that's correct I would be happy to know like what led you to this solution, when do you usually think about sums in these questions.

Comment: @MattiP. Another question is: I could say also that the second room must have between 50 to 100 people? and choose 50,51,...,100 from 250. would that also be true?